# why i get the next errors?

Tags: android, android-studio

i got the next errors when opened my proyect, how i should fix it?
cannot resolve "widget"
cannot resolve "app"
cannot resolve "content"
...
[image: i got the next errors when opened my proyect, how i should fix it?]

Comment: In IntelliJ 2021.3 JetBrains introduced a new way to help with such issues named Repair IDE. If you have Android Studio Electric Eel (or newer) you should be able to use it via: File -> Repair IDE. This usually helps me, hope it helps you too.

Comment: Perform a Gradle Sync "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing in build.gradle->dependencies->classpath
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'  to classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")